# Is there a fix for Mac OS to convert .efx files to PDF or Word with eMessenger?

Tags: macos, efax

As others have noted, the free version of eFax no longer allows the free faxes to be downloaded in a usable format.  Any one find a fix for that for Mac users?

Comment: Unfortunately, this no longer works on Lion as Power PC support has been dropped.

Answer (score 2):

Paid users can request pdf rather than efx format. Free users can do the following--

The following solution works fine for faxes of 1-3 pages, but is tedious for anything longer:

Login in to your efax account and view the fax. You can see one page of the fax at a time by clicking into the 'fax viewer' tab. To download a page of the fax, right-click on the page and choose 'save image as...'. This will download a page of the fax to your local storage in .png format that can be opened by many programs including OS X' bundled Preview.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to convert EFX files to PDF on all versions of the eFax software if you are using a Mac. Simply open the file to view it as normal with either the free or paid efax software, click on PRINT and then click on PDF. Follow the menus to save as a PDF file anyplace you wish on your hard drive. Simple.